# Windows installation fails, copying files is "too fast", seems related to SSD

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, ssd, windows-installation

I am helping someone install Windows on a new SSD, but so far it hasn't worked out.
I think the following things are relevant:

- The SSD is brand new
- SMART data says it's in perfect health
- The SSD is installed into the PC with a PCIe card
- A different SSD in the same slot does boot on the PC
- Both are UEFI
- Booting the install USB without UEFI initially allowed me to go through the process, with no different results and then an error, which disallowed me from booting that way again
- This SSD plugged into the other PC doesn't work either, not for booting and not for installing.
- Different USB's for the Windows installation make no difference
- I have reformatted the SSD several times

  - Using the installer, diskpart, Explorer, disk manager, Gparted and nvme-util command line utility on Linux ("regular" and secure erase)
- Whenever running the installation, the first step, Copying files, is done in like 2 seconds and jumps from 0% straight to 100%.
- I ran the Windows installation troubleshooting tool and it said there was something wrong with the installation files.
- The PC is relatively old, but since the other SSD does boot, I don't think it's a compatibility question.

My conclusion is there's something wrong with the SSD, but I don't know what and if it's fixable or not, or if the SSD is just broken somehow.
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What exact model is the new SSD?

Comment: It's a Kingston NV1 500GB

Comment: This is an NVMe disk. If your slot is for SATA, it can't work.

Comment: Yes it is an NVMe, and the SSD is recognised, that's not the problem, just that after installing Windows, it won't boot from it.